# How do I implicitly specialise conversion?

Tags: c++, class, templates

With the following code, if I attempt to convert a template array to std::string, instead of the compiler using the expected std::string conversion method, it raises an ambiguity resolution problem (as it attempts to call the array conversion methods):

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA
{
    public:
        TemplateItem Array[10];

        operator const TemplateItem *() const {return Array;}
        operator const std::string() const;
};

template<>
TestA<char>::operator const std::string() const
{
    std::string Temp("");
    return Temp;
}

int main()
{
    TestA<char> Test2;
    std::string Temp("Empty");
    Temp = Test2; //Ambiguity error. std::string or TemplateItem * ? 
    return 0;
}
```

What modification do I need to make to the code in order to make it so the code correctly and implicitly resolve to the std::string conversion function? Especially given the const TemplateItem * would be treated as a null-terminated array (which it won't likely be).

Comment: as `operator std::string` returns by value, it doesn't need to be `const std::string`.  Does that get rid of the problem?

Comment: @MooingDuck: Changing it from const to non-const has no notable effect. It might be worth noting std::string has three different conversion functions, one of which takes a char array, the other a std::string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the reason you have ambiguity: you provide both conversion to `char*` and conversion to `std::string const`, and `std::string` likes them both.

By the way, before getting to your question, the `const` in `operator std::string const` was once a good idea, advocated by e.g. Scott Meyers, but is nowadays ungood: it prevents efficient moving.

Anyway, re the question, just avoid implicit conversions. Make those conversions explicit. Now I answered that in response to another SO question, and someone (I believe the person was trolling) commented that C++98 doesn't support `explicit` type conversion operators. Which was true enough, technically, but pretty stupid as a technical comment. Because you don't need to use the `explicit` keyword (supported by C++11), and indeed that's not a good way to make the conversions explicit. Instead just *name* those conversions: use named member functions, not conversion operators.

---

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename TemplateItem>
class TestA
{
    public:
        TemplateItem Array[10];

        TemplateItem  const* data() const { return Array; }
        std::string str() const;
};

template<>
std::string TestA<char>::str() const
{
    return "";
}

int main()
{
    TestA<char> test2;
    std::string temp( "Empty" );
    temp = test2.str();     // OK.
    temp = test2.data();    // Also OK.
}
```

Cheers & hth.

Comment: Do you have a source which explains const being inefficient? It would be interesting to read.

Comment: A demo of a named conversion operator wouldn't go amis.

Comment: @Pubby8: `const` prevents move operations.  Previously people used "swaptimization" to get that efficiency.  Move operations make the compiler do it automatically.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: there is no such thing as a "named conversion operator". However, named conversions are plenty of in the standard library. E.g. `std::string::c_str()`, or `std::ostringstream::str()`.

Comment: I would have logically thought that std::string would have used operational precedence for one of it's own type over calling a templated function.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach: Fine.  I used the wrong word.  I even gave the answer a +1.  It would still be better with a bit of sample code to clarify how to do conversion properly as per the third paragraph.

Comment: @SSight3: as far a C++ is concerned, nope.  All assignment operators are just functions, and all equal.  (Almost.  It prefers `const` functions to non-`const` functions, but if your assignment operator is `const` you should be kept away from code)

Comment: @SSight3: at the place of the assignment there is no templating left anywhere, all is already concrete, instantiated. So the two possible conversions are on a completely equal footing.

Comment: @MooingDuck: I meant more in the case of [conversion operator precedent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092714/conversion-precedence-in-c)

Comment: Are saying that implicit conversion operators are generally bad or did I misread?

Answer (score 0):

I will add, after thinking about it, here's the reasoning and what should be done:

The operator const TemplateItem *(); Should be deleted.

Why? There never will be an instance where you would want implicit conversion of TestA (or any template class) to a TemplateItem array with an unknown size - because this has absolutely no bounds checking (array could be sizeof 1 or 10 or 1000 or 0) and would likely cause a crash if a calling function or class received the array with no idea what size it is.

If the array is needed, either use the operator[] for direct items, or GetArray (which would signal the user intends to pass an unknown-length array).

Retain operator const std::string. Code will compile. Possible memory issues down the line averted.

(Alf for his efforts has been selected as the 'correct' answer, although this is the more logical option)