# Overloaded constructor - constructur with bool argument has precedence

Tags: c++, type-conversion, overloading

I recently came across a class like the following

```
class Foo {
public:
    Foo(std::string msg) {}
private:
    Foo(bool b) {}
};
```

I noticed that trying to create an object of this class by means of

```
Foo foo("blah");
```

causes a compilation error telling that `Foo::Foo(bool)` is private. Apparently, if the argument is not an actual std::string, the compiler prefers to use the constructor with the `bool` argument. On the other hand, if the private constructor is not given, above code compiles just fine.

Why is it that the "`bool`-constructor" has precedence over the "`string`-constructor" althogh the type of the passed argument does not fit to any of them? Is this just a matter of definition or does it have a deeper meaning and some good reason?

Comment: Not sure about the *why*, but they should (probably) both be `explicit`.

Comment: actually, the explicit keyword does not change the behavior

Comment: It wouldn't in this case.

Comment: duplicate of [String literal matches bool overload instead of std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14770252/string-literal-matches-bool-overload-instead-of-stdstring)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason has to do with conversion operator precedence.  Each of the calls includes an implicit conversion

1. pointer -> `std::string`
2. pointer -> `bool`

In this case #1 is a user defined conversion and #2 is a language / compiler defined one.  User defined conversions have a much lower precedence and hence the other conversion is preferred.

**Edit**

Here is a similar question which has a much more in depth explanation of the precedence checks involved

> [conversion precedence in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1092714/23283)

Comment: Is this in the spec somewhere?

Comment: @nick look in appendix B.2

Comment: if by speck you mean the standard, yes, it's in **§13.3.3.2,2**: *When comparing the basic forms of implicit conversion sequences [...]
- a standard conversion sequence [...] is a better conversion sequence than a user-defined conversion
sequence* (`const char* -> bool` is a standard conversion sequence)