# Implicit casting C++

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Consider this case:

```
ClassA obA;
ClassB obB;

obA = obB;
```

Is it right, that if `ClassA` has a constructor which has a parameter of type `ClassB`, it will be called in this case?

If there is an overloaded casting operator in `ClassB` - which converts `ClassB` object to `ClassA` object, the operator method will be called. If there is corresponding constructor and overloaded casting operator which one will be called? Where can I read about it?

Comment: Take a look at this question, it might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092714/conversion-precedence-in-c

Comment: That's not casting, that's conversion.

Comment: Once we get past OP's confusion of operator= with calling a constructor, this seems to answer the question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384007/conversion-constructor-vs-conversion-operator-precedence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it right, that if `ClassA` has a constructor which has a parameter of type `ClassB`, it will be called in this case?

Yes, constructors are considered for implicit type conversions:

> **Type conversions of class objects can be specified by constructors** and by conversion functions. These
>   conversions are called user-defined conversions and are used for implicit type conversions (Clause 4), for
>   initialization (8.5), and for explicit type conversions (5.4, 5.2.9).

A constructor with the signature `ClassA::ClassA(ClassB)` is called a *converting-constructor*. During a function call such as the assignment, constructors and user-defined conversion operators are compiled into an overload set and the best one is chosen for the conversion.

If a constructor is chosen: If the source type is a by-value type, it creates a prvalue of the type of the source type (`ClassA`) initialized with the type of the destination type (`ClassB`), and that is used to initialize the parameter. If the source type is a reference, [reference-initialization rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization) are used.

---

The assignment operators are implicitly-generated in `ClassA` (assuming they haven't been overriden). They are:

```c++
ClassA& operator=(ClassA const&);
ClassA& operator=(ClassA      &&);
```

An implicit-conversion sequence can choose either a constructor or conversion function to convert from `ClassB -> ClassA const&` or `ClassB -> ClassA&&`.

However, in this case, going by your scenario, the conversion would not be able to succeed as it would be ambiguous. Consider:

```c++
struct B { operator struct A(); };

struct A {
    A() = default;
    A(B) {}
};

B::operator A() { return A(); }

int main() 
{
    A a; B b;
    a = b; // Error! Ambiguous conversion
}
```

Both `A::A(B)` and `B::operator A()` are both viable conversion functions to use for the conversion. As such, the conversion is ambiguous and we are given a compile error.

> User-defined conversions are applied only where they are unambiguous (10.2, 12.3.2).

If we change the signature of the converting-constructor in class `A` to `A::A(B const&)`, then the conversion operator in `B` will be used because the `A`'s constructor requires a qualification-conversion (addition of `const`).

There is a thread on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator) where you can learn more.

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
ClassA obA;
ClassB obB;

obA = obB;
```

is not what you think it is **(*)**. This code:

```
ClassB obB;
ClassA  obA = obB;
```

will work (as provided) if:

**1.** `ClassA` has constructor, that accepts `ClassB` as parameter:

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA(const ClassB& b)
    {
        //construct *this from b
    }
};
```

**2.** `ClassB` has defined conversion-to-type operator:

```
class ClassB
{
public:
    operator ClassA() const
    {
        //construct ClassA from *this
    }
};
```

> If there is an overloaded casting operator in ClassA which has a parameter of type ClassB [...].

You meant **constructor**, not **casting operator**, right? You try to convert `ClassA` to `ClassB`, so conversion operators from `ClassA` are irrelevant in this case.

---

**(*)** You assign `obB` to `obA` after `obA`'s construction, so in your case only second point is applicable. You can also make it work by adding assignment operator:

**3.**

```
class ClassA
{
public:
    ClassA& operator=(const ClassB& b)
    {
        //assign b to *this
    }
};
```

which would be called in your case.

Comment: Good call about #1. Of note is that if someone tries both #1 and #2, then they'll run into circular reference issues.