# Implicit const/nonconst operator bool

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Consider the following class:

```
class foo
{
public:
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept;
    constexpr operator void * &() noexcept;
    constexpr operator void * const &() const noexcept;
    constexpr operator void const * &() noexcept;
    constexpr operator void const * const &() const noexcept;
};
```

A `foo` object would be used like this:

```
void bar(bool);
// ...
foo f;
bar(f); // error C2664: cannot convert argument 1 from 'foo' to 'bool'
        // message : Ambiguous user-defined-conversion
        // message : see declaration of 'bar'
```

The issue is that the `operator bool` is not considered because of its `const`ness. If I make another function without the `const` qualifier, the problem is solved. If I make `f` const, the problem is solved as well. If I explicitly cast `f` to bool, the problem is solved.

[Sample to work with](https://godbolt.org/z/72LAdA)

What are my other options and what is causing this ambiguity?

Comment: make conversion operators `explicit`

Comment: @user7860670 I'd like them to be implicit.

Comment: You wrote "I don't even understand why this is happening in the first place." - it is happening because c++ for whatever reason allows implicit conversions. They drastically complicate overload resolution and adding more implicit user-defined conversion operators only makes things worse.

Comment: It seems like you already have enough implicit conversions for one more `constexpr operator bool() noexcept;` not to matter. I do agree with @user7860670 that its better to have none in the first place.

Comment: @user7860670 Blaming "C++ is overcomplicated" is not a satisfactory answer.

Comment: @BennyK Why isn't it resolving the already-made bool operator that is const? Sure, I can do it, but why is this happening in the first place?

Comment: Overloads #2 and #4 are better fits for the function `bar` because they aren't constant.
According to this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion, the "qualification adjustment" (i.e. const to non-const) is last in line.

Answer (score 1):

First you should have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092714/conversion-precedence-in-c) regarding conversion precedence in C++.

Then as pointed by some comments, `operator bool()` was not selected by the compiler for this conversion and the ambiguous resolution message is not about it.

The ambiguity comes from `constexpr operator void * &() noexcept` versus `constexpr operator void const * &() noexcept`. The idea being: let's try to convert a non const object to something and then see if this something can be converted to bool.

Also `operator void const*()` and `operator void*()` are redundant because there is no situation when you can call one and not the other and you can get a `const void*` from a `void*`.

Also returning `void const * const &` does not have any advantage over returning `void const*` as you won't be able to modify the reference. Returning a pointer instead of a reference to a pointer at worst does not change anything, at best, prevent you from doing a double indirection.

My advice would be to remove the non const operators and replace them by an explicit setter when you want to change the underlying pointer stored in `foo`. But that might not be the solution you are looking for depending on your actual problem and your design choices.

Comment: "the compiler does not even consider `operator bool()` here" - This is incorrect. If the other functions are removed, `operator bool()` is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the following, simplified, code:

```
struct foo {
    constexpr operator bool() const noexcept; // (1)
    constexpr operator void * &() noexcept; // (2)
    constexpr operator void const * &() noexcept; // (3)
};

void bar(bool);

// ...

foo f;
bar(f);
```

The [implicit conversion rules](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion) state the following:

> **Order of the conversions**
>
> Implicit conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one standard conversion sequence;
> 2. zero or one user-defined conversion;
> 3. zero or one standard conversion sequence.

The conversion of the argument in `bar` is one user-defined conversion, followed by one standard conversion sequence.

Continued:

> ... When converting from one built-in type to another built-in type, only one standard conversion sequence is allowed.
> A standard conversion sequence consists of the following, in this order:
>
> 1. zero or one conversion from the following set: lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, array-to-pointer conversion, and function-to-pointer conversion;
> 2. zero or one numeric promotion or numeric conversion;
> 3. zero or one function pointer conversion; (since C++17)
> 4. zero or one qualification adjustment.

There are planty of types that can be used where a `bool` is required, and pointers are amongst them, so for overloads #2 and #3 all that is required is one "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion". To use overload #1 the compiler will have to perform a "qualification adjustment" (`const bool` to `bool`).

---

How to fix this:

Remove ambiguity by adding the `constexpr operator bool() noexcept;`, which fits `bar` exactly.